# Change the value of item using input element from get method

Tags: php, html, laravel

i just want to clarify i have this get method where i can show the days of the months using this code in my controller;

```
$days=array();
$month = 0;
$year = 2018;
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
$time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);  
if(date('m', $time)==$month && date('w', $time)>0 && date('w', $time)<6) {
     $days[]=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
}
}
```

Now is it possible to changed the **month** value using **input** or **drop-down** select in html? something like a drop-down button with list of number correspond to month number example: value=1 name January,value=2 name February and when i select the month the days will come out..

Comment: Please study the usage of html markup `<select>` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Yes, it is. But if you want it to change dynamically using php code you will have to implement ajax calls.

Comment: @Jerodev how do i implement ajax ? can show me similar example?